# Is it possible to send ERC20 tokens to a contract address like sending ether?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, erc-20

Can we send ERC20 tokens to a contract address??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any address (contract or not) can be the recipient of ERC20 tokens.

The token contract keeps track of each address's balance. The implementation is usually very simple; just a mapping of addresses to their balances. The `transfer` method implementation probably won't do anything aside from check the sender's balance before making the transfer.

For more details see [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#Transfer_Token_Balance).

Comment: Make sure the contract your sending tokens has some way to send tokens ( or acknowledge tokens have been received), otherwise the tokens will be stuck, nontransferable.  Often you have to first approve the token, then tell the smart contract to transfer, so it's aware of this token.  Check out ERC165, ERC820